# TypeScript autocomplete/intellisense not working in i18n React Native/Expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

## TypeScript is not completing text in .json file correctly

- It always adds some text before the key
- For example, TypeScript is suggesting:

`{t("ns1:general.app-description")}`

- The correct thing would just be:

`{t("general.app-description")}`

- Without this `ns1:` at the beginning of the text.
- How can I resolve this? Below is the project structure:

### src > @types > i18next.d.ts

```
import "i18next";

import ns1 from "@/translations/en.json";
import ns2 from "@/translations/pt-br.json";

declare module "i18next" {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    defaultNS: "ns1";
    resources: {
      ns1: typeof ns1;
      ns2: typeof ns2;
    };
  }
}
```

### src > translations > i18n.tsx

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import en from "./en.json";
import pt_br from "./pt-br.json";

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  lng: "pt_br",
  fallbackLng: "en",
  compatibilityJSON: "v3",
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: en,
    },
    pt_br: {
      translation: pt_br,
    },
  },
});

export default i18n;
```

### src > translations > en.json

```
{
  "general": {
    "app-name": "myApp",
    "app-description": "Management"
  }
}
```

- Is there any configuration for TypeScript to not suggest this `ns1:`?

[Example of what autocomplete looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bKGk.png)

I followed the example at: https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript and it still isn't working correctly.